# Cast Image using Input command for ROKU

Tags: java, android

into below command what to replace for cast new image ? also need to know which code segment should be constant. please help

http://192.168.X.X:8060/input/15985?u=http%3A%2F%2F192.168.1.31%3A8000%2Fstorage%2Femulated%2F0%2FPictures%2FMusicPlayer%2FAlbum_1697522130300.png&t=p&tr=crossfade&h=%28null%29

Answer (score 0):

For cast images, you only need to change your local server URL after the URL PORT.

http://192.168.X.X:8060/input/15985?u=http%3A%2F%2F192.168.1.31%3A8000%2F**change_this_segment**&t=p&tr=crossfade&h=%28null%29

Don't use same url every time while cast the image, so change my mentioned position with image path which will make URL unique.